# Creating new Array from previous Array values in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of strings called groups that I am looping through with a forEach, what I want to do is create a new array where each string is the name of it.

I have tried to create the arrays with `let [group] = []` but that gives an Identifier group has already been declared error. Any help appreciated

Code:

```
let groups = ['a','b','c']
//forEach loop creates an array for each string in groups
groups.forEach(group => {
            let [group] = []
            //Adding things to new array here
        })
//Each new array from groups is added to an object/array that is returned by the function
```

Comment: do you have some data and the wanted result? why not take an object?

Comment: @NinaScholz some basic data would be groups contains something like ['a' , 'b', 'c'] and after there would be three arrays named a , b , and c

Comment: how do you like to access the arrays?

Comment: after creating `three arrays named a , b , and c` are you going to access it like a javascript varible? If so, that is not possible

Comment: @NinaScholz what exactly do you mean by that? Not sure I understand the question

Comment: how do you know, that you need variable `a` for access?

Comment: Oh no it would not be accesed like a varible

Comment: but how????????

Comment: please show a javascript object/array as a sample data and another javascript object/array as output and add both in your question

Comment: My plan for these arrays is that they would be added to different object/array that would be returned by the function

Comment: If you add the input and the output of how you want it, that would be much easier to solve your problem, please do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use forEach, reduce is appropriate for array -> object transform:

```
const myGroups = groups.reduce((acc, group) => {
  let arr = [];
  // add stuff here
  return Object.assign({}, acc, {[group]: arr});
}, {});
```

this will give you an object where the "group" value is the keys and whatever arrays you created are the values. if the same group value appears more than once, the earlier values will be overwritten.

Comment: you could just do `acc[group] = []; return acc;` instead of `let arr = [];
  return Object.assign(acc, {[group]: arr});`

Comment: Avoiding mutative methods is a habit best reinforced constantly

Comment: @bryan60 but `Object.assign` is a mutative method? - `Object.assign({}, acc, {[group]: arr})` would not mutate acc

Comment: I meant to put the leading `{}` in, fxed now

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
b = {};
a.forEach( x => {
    b[x] = [];
});
console.log(b);
```